# How to reuse camera after take a photo?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a simple question: how to use (show) again a camera after take a photo?

I use UIImagePickeController and when the photo was taken (Use button was tapped) we go to delegate:

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

How to tell camera to appears one again?

Comment: just save the image in the delegate, without dismissing the `picker`..

Comment: [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

Comment: Just create a new instance of UIImagePickerViewController in the callback ? Whats the problem ?